# Clean the contents in Bitbucket repo after the build job is completed in jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

As post build action in jenkins job, I would like to clean up the contents present in Bitbucket repo -> folder/branch. Bitbucket server version used is 4.14.

Kindly let me know, if there options available in Jenkins to connect back to bitbucket once the job is done.

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You may certainly execute a bash/console script after the Jenkins build is finished.  But what content do you want to remove from Bitbucket?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are currently executing git script to remove the files for bitbucket manually. We would like to achieve the same upon Jenkins build completion automatically. We would like to remove the old contents each time because the build need to fetch only new contents everytime.